# custom class-wise loss function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics, loss-function

For my problem, I want to **predict** customer **review scores ranging from 1 to 5**. 
I thought it would be good to implement this as a **regression problem** because a predicted 1 from the model while 5 being the true value should be a "worse" prediction than 4.
It is also wished, that the model performs somehow **equally good for all review score classes**. 
Because my dataset is **highly unbalanced** I want to **create a metric/loss** that is capable of capturing this (I think just as F1 for classification). 
Therefore I created following metric (for now just mse is relevant):

```
def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([y_pred, y_true]), columns=["Predicted", "Truth"])
    class_mse = 0
    #class_mae = 0
    print("MAE for Classes:")
    for i in df.Truth.unique():
        temp = df[df["Truth"]==i]
        mse = mean_squared_error(temp.Truth, temp.Predicted)
        #mae = mean_absolute_error(temp.Truth, temp.Predicted)
        print("Class {}: {}".format(i, mse))
        class_mse += mse
        #class_mae += mae
    print()
    print("AVG MSE over Classes {}".format(class_mse/len(df.Truth.unique())))
    #print("AVG MAE over Classes {}".format(class_mae/len(df.Truth.unique())))
```

Now an example prediction:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error

# sample predictions: "model" messed up at class 2 and 3 
y_true = np.array((1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5))
y_pred = np.array((1,1,1,2,2,3,5,4,3,4,4,4,5,5,5))

custom_metric(y_true, y_pred)
```

Now my question: Is it able to create a custom tensorflow loss function which is able to act in a similar behaviour? I also worked on this implementation which is not yet ready for tensorflow but maybe more alike:

```
def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    mse_class = 0
    num_classes = len(np.unique(y_true))
    stacked = np.vstack((y_true, y_pred))
    for i in np.unique(stacked[0]):     
        y_true_temp = stacked[0][np.where(stacked[0]==i)]
        y_pred_temp = stacked[1][np.where(stacked[0]==i)]
        mse = np.mean(np.square(y_pred_temp - y_true_temp))
        mse_class += mse
    return mse_class/num_classes
```

But still, I am not sure how to work around the for loop for a tensorflow like definition.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The for loop should be dealt with exactly by means of numpy/tensorflow operations on a tensor.

A custom metric example would be:

```
  from keras import backend as K

  def custom_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

where y_true is the ground truth label, y_pred are your predictions. You can see there are not explicit for-loops.

The motivation for not using for loops is that vectorized operations (which are present both in numpy and tensorflow) take advantage of the modern CPU architectures, turning multiple iterative operations into matrix ones. Consider that a dot-product implementation in numpy takes approximately 30 times less than a regular for-loop in Python.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I think I could do something like `mean_squared_error(y_true[np.where(y_true==1)],y_pred[np.where(y_true==1)])` for every class and compute the global mean (not pretty but a start). But now I am stuck translating `(y_true[np.where(y_true==1)]` into tensorflow. I will try further to make it work :)

Comment: You do not need to. You can directly send y_true and y_pred. Since you frame your problem as a regression one, the MSE will automatically penalize more a prediction of a real number 4.2 than a 2.1 when the ground truth is 1.0 for example.Your y_true(ground truth) in this case is a real number. Therefore, you don't need any one-hot-encoding.

Comment: But a simple implementation of mean squared error doesn't take care about the imbalance of the classes or am I missing something? Thats why I wanted to do the mean MSE over all the review classes. So that a bad performance on a small class (1 star reviews) gets penalized more even though the class is relatively small.

Comment: Okay, pay attention to the fact that a **loss function** and a **metric** are two different things :D, that's where the confusion comes from. The function defined above should be used as a loss_function during the training of your neural network. For regression problems, the "MSE" = mean_squared_error is the loss function. Other metrics that you can use during the training are :
    Mean Absolute Error: mean_absolute_error, MAE, mae
    Mean Absolute Percentage Error: mean_absolute_percentage_error, MAPE
    Cosine Proximity: cosine_proximity, cosine

Comment: Imbalance is another kettle of fish, you can use SMOTE or ADASYN or other such oversampling techniques in order to balance your dataset.